# Create copy of Object

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, icloneable

I need to clone object (class, not struct) in .net 4.5 (c#).

 I found two ways:

1. Implement [ICloneable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)
2. Create own clone mechanism like [this famous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/1616443)

I like fist way - it's easier, but I also found [Not Implpement ICloneable Interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx), but it's very old post and on MSDN I can't find that this interface deprecated.

Could any says me, it is safety to use ICloneable  in .net 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the IClonable interface.

[Here's a blog from Brad Abrams discussing why not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx) from several years ago. Basically, the reasons are outlined by Tim Schmelter's answer, but this blog is from the horse's mouth.

In relation to implementing cloning via serialization, there is a slightly better way available now because we can specify [`StreamingContextStates.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontextstates.aspx) to allow the cloning to work better with things like unmanaged handles.

There's a canonical implementation in "CLR via C# 4th Edition" by Jeffrey Richter which goes like this:

```
public static object DeepClone(object original)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter
        {
            Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone)
        };

        formatter.Serialize(stream, original);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Or the strongly typed variant:

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T original)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "original");
    }

    if (ReferenceEquals(original, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter
        {
            Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone)
        };

        formatter.Serialize(stream, original);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return (T) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

I reckon you should use that (where possible) instead of implementing `IClonable`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Brad Abrams post is also old (2004). I need shadow clone of my object. What do you think about Object.MemberwiseClone Method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx  ps - Way with serialize/deserialize looks nise. Allredy found 3 or 4 different implementation

Comment: @jimpanzer Have a read of the serialization section, it's very interesting. ;)   Anyway, I wouldn't use `MemberwiseClone()` because it is only a *shallow* clone - unless you only want a shallow clone, of course.

Answer (score 3):

`IClonable` is just an interface so it *does* nothing until you implement it. The post which suggests to not use `IClonable` mentions why: it is not clear if `Clone` is implemented as deep- or as shallow copy.

So just provide a `Copy` or `DeepClone` method and everyone knows what happens.

Quote to explain the two terms:

> There are two general ways to implement ICloneable, either as a **deep**,
>   or **non-deep** copy. Deep-copy copies the cloned object and all objects
>   referenced by the object, recursively until all objects in the graph
>   are copied. A non-deep copy (referred to as **shallow** if only the top
>   level references are copied) may do none, or part of a deep copy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need shadow clone of my object. What do you think about Object.MemberwiseClone Method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx